# python 2.7 storing a float and a string from the same raw_input line

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, floating-point, raw-input

I am trying to get python 2.7 to store a single line of input that contains both a string and three float numbers so that I can perform some averages, etc.

ex. input:   Tom 25 30 20

I tried:

```
name, score1, score2, score3 = raw_input().split()
score1, score2, score3 = [float(score1),float(score2),float(score3)]
```

but it throws an "invalid literal" error due to the string.  Additionally, my code feels bulky, would there be a simpler way to go about this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your code functions fine exactly as written, it does not throw any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor this a little, but what you have works and isn't that bulky or bad.

```
>>> user_input = raw_input('Enter your name and three numbers: ').strip().split()
Enter your name and three numbers: Tom 25 30 20
>>> name = user_input[0]
>>> scores = map(float, user_input[1:])
>>> name
'Tom'
>>> scores
[25.0, 30.0, 20.0]
```

Doing it this way means using a list (with subscripts like `scores[0]`, `scores[1]`) instead of variables with names like `n1`, `n2` (which always suggests to me you should be using a list).

Using `map` with `float` means you don't have to write `float(var)` three times.

You might also consider `strip()` on your user input. It's usually a good idea, especially since you're implicitly splitting on whitespace.

Comment: Also a comment on the invalid literal error. You can check whether your string for some reason contains any non-printing characters and strip them out before converting them to floating: `print repr(user_input)`

Comment: Yeah that is something different and we need more info from OP. Nothing posted in the question should cause that, AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you all for the added help. I was entering a string where it expected int before this, I just didn't catch it.  Python is my first endeavor into programming, only been at it for a few months now!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem like this:

```
input = raw_input("Give me the input [name number number number]: ").split(" ")
name = input[0]
floats = map(float, input[1:])
print "I'm your name ", name
print "I'm your floats ", floats
print "I'm a sample average ", sum(floats)/len(floats)
```

You can get any float with:

```
floats[i]
```